# conditionally applying class while expanding row in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In dataBound function of my Kendo grid i want to make condition, if master row, from header is expanded, apply class "customClass" to this row.
I tried:

```
    $('.k-master-row.k-state-active td').each(function(){$(this).addClass('customClass')})
```

it doesn't work, there is no effect, in best case I can apply class to expanded row, no way to do this on header. Any solution? Thanks

Angular JS:

```
 $scope.gridMaterialDefinitionProperties = function (dataItem) {

        return {
            dataSource: f_GetDataSourceMaterialDefinitionProperties(dataItem),
            dataBound: function (e) {

  //               $('.k-master-row.k-state-active td').each(function(){$(this).addClass('customClass')})
          $(this).parent().css( "color", "red" );
                f_OnDataBound(e);
            },
```

HTML:

```
<div kendo-grid="gridMaterialDefinitionProperties" k-options="gridMaterialDefinitionProperties(dataItem)">
    <div k-detail-template>
        <kendo-tabstrip>
            <ul>
                <li id="tabStripgridMaterialDefinitionHeadersPropertyAny" class="k-state-active">TXT_PROPERTY_ANY</li>
                <li id="tabStripgridMaterialDefinitionHeadersPropertiesComment">@PLanguageTexts.TXT_COMMENT</li>
            </ul>
            <div kendo-grid="gridMaterialDefinitionPropertyAny" k-options="gridMaterialDefinitionPropertyAny(dataItem)" ng-hide="dataSource.length===0">    </div>
            <div>
                <textarea class="textarea-gridComment" ng-model="dataItem.Comment" ng-change="OnCommentChange(dataItem, gridMaterialDefinitionProperties)"></textarea>
            </div>
        </kendo-tabstrip>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need more details. Show the other code and html

Comment: i have 1100 rows of JS, and local db, it wouldnt help, i think

Comment: only add the code about this issue and html of how the result is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way to determine if a row is currently expanded or not:

- Check the CSS class of the arrow icon in the first cell - **k-plus** for collapsed and **k-minus** for expanded.
- Check the visibility of the next detail row. If it has the **display: none;** style, then the row is collapsed.

Comment: does it mean that something like this should work? 
if(".k-icon.k-plus"){
              $("td").css( "color", "red" );
            }

I am not sure what to use with "td" to select only header row, not whole grid

Comment: If the style should be added to the master row, you could use $(".k-icon.k-minus").closest("tr").css("color", "red");